# What is a .un~ file or why does Vim in the Terminal make the .un~ file?

Tags: vim, terminal, dotfiles

I've noticed I have some dotfiles that end with `.un~`

For example I have a `.vividchalk.vim.un~`, but I'm not sure where that came from.

It seems like they are created when I use Vim in the Terminal.

What are these files? Can have them remove themselves when I close the file I'm editing?

Answer (score 169, accepted):

When you edit and save files, Vim creates a file with the same name as the original file and an `un~` extension at the end.

Vim 7.3 contains a new feature persistent undo, that is, undo information
won't be lost when quitting Vim and be stored in a file that ends with `.un~`.
You have set the `undofile` option, so Vim creates an undo file when saving
the original file. You can stop Vim from creating the backup file, by
clearing the option:

```
:set noundofile
```

Note that, by default this option is turned off. You have explicitly
enabled the `undofile` option in one of the initialization files. If you
want your undofiles to be stored only in a particular directory, you can
point the `undodir` option to a directory that will contain all your
aggregated undofiles.

Source: http://vimhelp.appspot.com/vim_faq.txt.html#faq-7.2

Comment: Thanks! I'm new to Vim and trying to understand and configure without cargo culting. I see now that setting is coming from `vim-sensible`. Reading the ReadMe on [vim-sensible](https://github.com/tpope/vim-sensible) is very helpful. And I learned (from a peepcode screencast) that I can do `:verbose set undofile?` and I'll see where that option is set. I think I have that right.

Comment: I have Vim 7.3 and persistent undo isn't working for me (I need to have `set undofile` to get the persistent undo). Do other settings interfere with the new feature, e.g. `nobackup` or `noswapfile`?

Comment: I think the cream non-cream-vim-installer also sets this enabled by default.

Comment: Oh man!! now I have to remember: `set nobackup
set noswapfile
set noundofile` in every _vimrc if I don't want puppy tracks??!!  You'd think ONE of those could default to off or something...

Comment: It appears as if vim 8 (at least 8.0.427) has this feature turned on by default. YMMV of course...

Comment: Just notifying that Vim installed on Windows with the default .exe installer found at vim.org does enable this option by default. At least as of 8.2.

Answer (score 13):

Took me a while to find where to actually put the `:set noundofile` command. I am new and I’ll just reply with how I made it not do backups.

1. Open vim.
2. Type in command mode `:e $HOME/.vimrc`
3. Write `:set noundofile`
4. Save & quit: `:wq`

Comment: It works for my use case, that is a little bit different: using Vim inside ConEmu on Windows. Thanks!

Comment: I got undofiles by default on vim windows installer. Your guide helped me, thanks!

Comment: Please don't! Undo is an extremely valuable feature. You just need to define an [undodir](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64352537/6419007).

Comment: This answer was what worked for me. Thanks.

Answer (score 12):

Another possible way to avoid vim creating undo files everywhere is set set the [undodir](https://vimhelp.org/options.txt.html#%27undodir%27) to some existing directory, e.g.

```
if has('persistent_undo')         "check if your vim version supports
  set undodir=$HOME/.vim/undo     "directory where the undo files will be stored
  set undofile                    "turn on the feature
endif
```

[snagged from here](https://riptutorial.com/vim/example/25592/configuring-your-vimrc-to-use-a-undodir)

Comment: Exactly. Vim undo is an extremely valuable tool (when it doesn't litter your folders). I love `:earlier 30m`, for example.