# Cleaning up after: git commit -m using single quote - error pathspec on windows git-cmd.exe and vim

Tags: git, vim, cmd, git-bash

I just started using git in Windows. I am using the latest PortableGit version 2.30.1 and I believe I have set them up correctly.

I am just trying to practice with git's more advanced features such as branching, merging, tagging etc. So I created a simple mock project for it.

I just started the project. The project has only 2 files currently: f1.py and .gitignore.
It currently only has 2 commits.

The problem is that in my last (2nd) commit, I have incorrectly use single quote for git commit message and it complains of pathspec error:

```
C:\ex\gitpractice>git commit -m 'Modified A1 -> A2'
error: pathspec 'A1' did not match any file<s> know to git
error: pathspec '-' did not match any file<s> know to git
```

Then I tried:

```
C:\ex\gitpractice>git commit -m \'Modified A1 \-> A2'
fatal: \A1: '\A1' is outside repository at 'C:/ex/gitpractice'
```

Which resulted in something 'fatal', I know, I was so stupid... Then I commited using the correct double-quote:

```
C:\ex\gitpractice>git commit -m "Modified A1 -> A2"
```

It was successfull. But anyway, I was left with multiple files, that I did not intentionally create. Anyway here is the screenshot of what has happened:

[image: git commit using single quote and the results]

As you could see, I tried removing the other files using `git rm` and it did not even work.
I also used Vim 8.2 to edit the files there (and I am just a beginner vim user). And I just knew today that I should not be using single quotes in git-cmd.exe in windows from https://github.com/cmderdev/cmder/issues/2052. But I was still left with the extra files created.

What happened during the 'fatal' commit? What are those extra files? Is it safe to remove them? Should / How can I remove them ?
(I usually used git and edited in nano in Ubuntu machines before)

Comment: You cannot use `git rm` if the files are not in the index. Just use `del <file>` (if I remember well) to delete them.

Comment: I think the question ended up not actually being about git (as the tag suggest) , but more on how to delete weird-named files in Windows

Comment: delete weird file names on windows in git-bash. Simplest solution is probably to just use Explorer :).

Comment: what re those files that ends with the ~ (tilde)? Is it vim related? But I had closed vim already, why is it still there? And is it safe to just delete them?

Comment: Note: it's just plain `cmd.exe`, which is (based on) the old MS-DOS command line interpreter and comes with Windows systems. It's not a very good command line interpreter. I don't use Windows but a lot of Windows programmers seem to like Powershell, which apparently is well integrated with Windows. As a Unix/Linux programmer I prefer sh or bash; there's a port of bash to Windows as well. Some versions of it are included with some Windows Git distributions.

Comment: Note also that bash has nothing to do with Git (though some Git programs are written as scripts that require a POSIX-compatible shell, and bash is sufficient to run those scripts). The file names ending with tilde characters are some editor's backup versions. `vim` and `emacs` can both be set up to do this; probably other editors can be as well. See, e.g., [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/607435/1256452). This too has nothing to do with Git itself.

Comment: @torek ok, yes they (*~) are vim files. I tried adding `set nobackup` to `C:\Program Files\Vim\_vimrc`, but I can't save, it's a read-only file. How can I add the `set nobackup` to the _vimrc ?

Comment: nvm. I figured it out : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30276164/how-to-edit-vimrc-file and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15660669/what-is-a-un-file-or-or-why-does-vim-in-the-terminal-make-the-un-file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically you executed `command > file`. `>` redirects the output of a command into a (new or existing) file. This works similar to the IO redirect operator in Linux shells.

Git didn't do anything, your shell did. In other words: the file is not tracked by Git, that's why you cannot `git rm` it ("pathspec" is Git language). Simply remove the (untracked) files with Windows Explorer or from cmd.exe:

```
del A2'
```

or

```
del A2*
```

Comment: Yes, you are correct. But `rm A2'` will only work in powershell, not in cmd.exe. I used `del A2'` in cmd.exe

Comment: @tek27 right, I missed that bit. Updated my answer to recommend `del` for cmd

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you're using the fancy-single quote `’`, not the simple one `'`. Not sure what causes that, but you shouldn't be using fancy quotes. Windows uses double quotes to create long string arguments.

From the standard windows command prompt, I can type

```
> del A<tab>
```

And the prompt will auto complete to the correct format to delete (`>` for `cmd` and `$` for `git-bash`):

```
# For the ' version
> del "A'"
$ rm A\'

# For the ’ version
> del A’
$ rm A’
```

`git rm` can't delete these files, because they aren't staged yet. So, git can't find the file in its index. And can't delete it. The error message is a bit misleading. The pathspec didn't match any files *git is aware of*.

Why were these created? Well, the `>` character puts the output into a file with the name behind it. And the `'` and `’` characters don't create an escaped string. Only `"` does.

Comment: I don't think the OP had a Microsoft-style smart-quote inflicted on his command: it's just that the old CMD.EXE shell simply doesn't have single quote as a quoting character, so that `-m 'this that'` means the equivalent of a sane shell's `-m "'this" "that'"`.